# KB3185331 and "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

I'm working on a Windows 8.1, x64 workstation. Windows Update cannot install the latest set of Microsoft patches. I'm trying to manually install KB3185331, which is the security rollup patches. Manual installation is failing with the following error in the Setup events:

```
Windows update "Security Update for Windows (KB3185331)" could not be installed because of
error 2147942402 "The system cannot find the file specified." (Command line: 
""C:\Windows\system32\wusa.exe" "C:\Users\JW\Downloads\Windows8.1-KB3185331-x64.msu" ")
```

I tried to follow the *"Get Help with this Error"* link in Windows Update, but that's about as useful as a boar with tits. Its been broken for years, and I'm guessing Microsoft has no plans to fix it to ensure it meets user's expectations.

I searched the computer for a more specific log file, but Windows Search does not reveal any hits for KB3185331. I searched the web for the KB number are error message, but there's [only one hit in German](http://www.google.com/search?q=KB3185331+and+"The+system+cannot+find+the+file+specified").

Following th German page's advice did not fix the problem. Wbem's `winmgmt /verifyrepository` returned consistent. Following [KB971058, How do I reset Windows Update components?](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971058) and the *FixIt!* claimed to fix some problems, but the issue persisted after reboot.

I have a few questions:

- Why is the installation failing?
- What file cannot be found?
- How do I fix it?

---

Here's one of the useless error messages. Its encountered when trying to manually install the rollup.

[image]

Comment: share the folder C:\windows\logs\CBS so that I can analyze it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it was due to Microsoft's "forced upgrade" policy combined with broken update processes.

My Windows installations are hardened. They remove unwanted garbage, like Skype and OneDrive. The "missing file" was one of the files that were deleted after unwanted components were removed. I never tracked down which one, but the update succeeded after I (1) cloned the VM, and (2) "repaired" the installation with tools like dsim. For item (2), see KB 947821, [Fix Windows Update errors by using the DISM or System Update Readiness tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947821).

The broken update process was never admitted to by Microsoft, but it was reported by Forbes at [Microsoft Confirms Massive Windows 7, Windows 8 Upgrade Changes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/gordonkelly/2016/12/08/microsoft-confirms-massive-windows-7-windows-8-upgrade-changes/#74c5895c5331).

So it appears Microsoft has a corporate policy of forcing users to retain and use unwanted services, and its enforced by technical controls like breaking updates for users who don't conform. Where is the US Department of Justice and Federal Trade Commission when you need them...

Answer (score 1):

This one has been driving me nuts for the last half hour! I was attempting to
run this script on a Windoze 7 box:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Apply Windows update files (*.msu) in the current directory.
for %%f in (*.msu) do echo %%f && Wusa.exe %%f /quiet /norestart
echo Done!
```

The fix? Start->Accessories Right Click "Command Prompt" and select "Run As Administrator"

This is indeed a very misleading error message, because the file exists but you don't have access to it. A better message might have been "Permission denied"

Comment: Thanks Russel. It was a good thought. The same issue occurs with *"Run As Administrator"*. Would you happen to know where the log files are? I can't find them, but Windows Search is nearly useless.